# How to round a Float by default?

Tags: haskell

I have a float `23.8` and I want to get `23` as an int.

Comment: [**`floor`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor)?

Comment: If you want `Int` type you can do like  `(floor 23.8 :: Int)`

Comment: That being said, usually it is better to stay in the integer world as much as (reasonably) possible, since it does not suffer that much from rounding errors.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of rounding methods such as:

- towards negative infinity: `floor 0.8 = 0`  and `floor (-0.8) = -1`
- positive infinity: `ceiling 0.8 = 1` and `ceiling (-0.8) = 0`
- zero: `truncate 0.8 = 0` and `truncate (-0.8) = 0`
- to even at the half ('bankers rounding'): `round 0.8 = 1`, `round (-0.8) = -1`, `round 0.5 = 0`, `round 1.5 = 2`

So from what you said you might want floor or truncate (`floor 23.8 = = truncate 23.8 = 23`) but ask yourself what you'd like to happen if this value is ever negative.

Answer (score 1):

Your description seems to indicate you want truncation, not rounding. For this you can use [`truncate`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/truncate_f.html):

> (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: They may also want `floor`. Compare: `floor (-0.8) = -1` vs `truncate (-0.8) = 0`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Great point - thanks.